# How do I rewire my existing garage lighting so that one fixture is controlled by a new switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I have one switch that turns on the 5 light fixtures in my garage. I would like to add a switch where only 1 light comes on to save wear and tear on all my light fixtures.

My thoughts are to run a new electrical line and light switch to my second light fixture. Disconnect the connecting line that goes between my first light and 2nd light fixture in line.

By leaving the first light on the original light switch all I have to do is run a new switch and line to the rest of my lights.

Does this sound correct?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I really need to know if I should do it the way I described, or is there a simpler way. When I go in my garage at night and hit the light switch I don't "need" all 5 lights to come on.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what you said. Disconnect the first light from the second. Run wire from the second light back to the location of the switch. If it is a single gang box, you will have to remove it and add a double gang box or put a double switch meant for a single gang box in. Tie into the power for the first light and use it to power the new wire to the second light.